# LTR text where it should be RTL (right to left) in beamer list second level

Tags: beamer, lists, right-to-left, bidi

I have this example of writing right to left list in beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\setRTL    
\raggedleft

  \begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The text which comes after the second level list is left to right where it should be right to left. The problem does not appear with other class

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}\null-}
\begin{document}

\setRTL    

 \begin{enumerate}
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize} 
   this text from right to left   
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about using the solution you already found with starting a new paragraph and undoing the additional space?

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\setRTL    
\raggedleft

  \begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}

   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know this, what  I can't understand is what's cause this. and how can I do this solution for every like situations ( perhaps `\usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody end}{.......}` )

Comment: Any help to automate your solution

Comment: @SalimBou Unfortunately I don't understand the mechanism of `bidi` enough to help with an automated solution. To analysis the problem: beamer redefined itemize and enumerate environments to make them overlay aware - thus they are defined slightly different than in normal document classes and the fixes `bidi` applies don't work any longer. However I don't really know what exactly would have to be changed...

Answer (score 3):

Solve with:

```
\let\olditemize=\itemize
\def\itemize{\vskip0pt\olditemize}
```

% Or

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\vskip0pt}
```

code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\let\olditemize=\itemize
\def\itemize{\vskip0pt\olditemize}

% Or

%\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\vskip0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\setRTL    
\raggedleft

  \begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

or: add `\vskip0pt` in

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{\vskip0pt% <--- add
  \ifblank{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\makeatother
```

code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[RTLdocument=on]{bidi}
\raggedleft

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{\vskip0pt% <--- add
  \ifblank{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Similarly, for the rest of the list environment, see the code below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[RTLdocument=on]{bidi}
\raggedleft

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\let\olditemize=\itemize
\def\itemize{\vskip0pt\olditemize}

\let\oldenumerate=\enumerate
\def\enumerate{\vskip0pt\oldenumerate}

\let\olddescription=\description
\def\description{\vskip0pt\olddescription}

% or 
%\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\vskip0pt}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\vskip0pt}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{\vskip0pt}

%++++++++++++++++++++++

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item one two
\end{itemize}
test right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test right
\begin{description}\raggedleft
\item[right]
test right
\end{description}
test right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test right
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item one two
\end{itemize}
test right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test right
\begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
\item one two
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item one two
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
test right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly. My train of thought was the following:

The "problem text" can be understood as an `\item`, except that the "bulletpoint" (the sign before the text) is omitted.

This can be done as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\setRTL    
\raggedleft

  \begin{enumerate}\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space 
    \vspace{-.6cm}
   \item[] \hspace{2cm} this text from right to left   % <-- problem was here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(The `\hspace{2cm}` command is just to show that you can move the text anywhere in the horizontal direction – analogous to the  `\vspace{-.6cm}` command.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Sure, I've already thought of your solution, but because I was unsure how exactly the solution has to look like, I gave my source code a kind of "free space", so that you can almost (if you want)  change the necessary things directly (a kind of template /Mask). But thanks for the hint! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in version 37 [bidi](https://ctan.org/pkg/bidi).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}

\setRTL    
%\raggedleft

  \begin{enumerate}%\raggedleft
  \item Data may be missing
    \begin{itemize}%\raggedleft
    \item This makes the problem complete 
    \item even for very restricted cases
    \end{itemize}  % \par solve the problem but add extra space
   this text from right to left   % <-- problem here 
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```